# Longest distance between straight line and a curve in UNITY

Tags: c#, distance, unity-game-engine

I've read a lot of questions that were "similar" to mine but no one has been good for me. The thing is that I want to know the longest distance from a curve and a straight line. The curve line is the touch input of the user, every point, and the straight line is from the start touch point to the end touch point.

[image: Here is an example of what I want to get]

What's the best and efficient way to achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is more mathematical problem than c# problem. There is this equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points which you can use to get the distance.

Comment: Basically you want the longest distance of all the shortest distances from any point on the line/curve. You'll have to calculate each candidate individually and choose the longest one.

Comment: Can you give us some code to work with? For example, how does the curve exist in your code? Is it an `IEnumerable<Point>`? How does your line exist – as two points?

Comment: Yes, I know that method to get the distance from a point to a line, but the problem i have is that i don´t know how to get that point that is the furthest one to the line @Fif

Comment: Since your line is hand-drawn and doesn't follow any mathematical rules, you will have to check multiple points of the user input and determine the longest normal to the line.

Comment: @Lumen The code is so simple that i did not include it. I am only getting the points from the user Touch Input and saving them into a Vector2 until the touch.phase = Ended

Comment: *"Yes, I know that method to get the distance from a point to a line"* *"The code is so simple that i did not include it."* So your actual question is how to get the largest of several numbers? Initialize a variable with zero, for every distance check if it's bigger than the variable (if yes --> variable = distance), return variable.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer So the best way to do it is that? Calculating each distance from every single point to the line and select the longest? I think i´m gonna do it this way since i didn´t find something easier.

Comment: Yep, that's basically it. I'd recommend omitting similar points to speed things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your curve is given by `IEnumerable<Point> curve` and your line is given by two points `start` and `end`.

```
Func<Point, double> distance = p =>
    Math.Abs(
          (end.Y - start.Y)*p.X
        - (end.X - start.X)*p.Y
        + end.X*start.Y
        - end.Y*start.X
    )
    / Math.Sqrt(
          (end.Y - start.Y)*(end.Y - start.Y)
        + (end.X - start.X)*(end.X - start.X));

Point nearest  = curve.OrderBy(distance).First();
Point farthest = curve.OrderByDescending(distance).First();
```

This is not the most efficient way to do it, because one iteration over the data would suffice and the sorting is overkill. However, there is no builtin `ArgMinAndMaxBy` in Linq, and speed might not be an issue.

You can, trivially, replace the type `Point` (from `System.Drawing`) by your `Vector2` type, by the way.

Comment: My curve is giving by a Vector2 of doubles. I don´t know if that Point that you have in your code is each of the values. I am pretty noob in C#, sorry.

EDIT: And well, speed is an issue, it would be better if its fast enough to not lag the game. That´s the major problem i have and i don´t know how to solve it.

Comment: @DanielBlanco I’m pretty sure you can just replace `Point` (from `System.Drawing`, by the way) by `Vector2`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking which is the longest distance between the straight line  and through the curve... the curve has the longest distance.. use the power of calculus where you can estimate the exactly distance of the curve by making use of straight line segments on the curve. the more line segments you can put in higher chance of improved approximation of the distance..